# Opencart SEO URL 404 not found

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, opencart

After enabling SEO URLs in OpenCart admin panel, all the links return 404 - not found.

My .htaccess file

```
# SEO URL Settings
RewriteEngine On
# If your opencart installation does not run on the main web folder make sure you folder it does run in ie. / becomes /shop/

RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^sitemap.xml$ index.php?route=extension/feed/google_sitemap [L]
RewriteRule ^googlebase.xml$ index.php?route=extension/feed/google_base [L]
RewriteRule ^system/storage/(.*) index.php?route=error/not_found [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !.*\.(ico|gif|jpg|jpeg|png|js|css)
RewriteRule ^([^?]*) index.php?_route_=$1 [L,QSA]
```

The site is located in `/var/www/html/opencurt`, I am trying to change to `RewriteBase /opencurt`, but it doesn't help me. I also cleared my cache.

The current URL on my local machine is `http://127.0.0.1/`

I know it's common problem, but I can't resolve it by myself.

Comment: What version of OC are you using? The htaccess file name is .htaccess or .htaccess.txt? 404 even on admin panel?

Comment: i use ocStore-3.0.2.0 and my OC Linux Mint, yes i rename .htaccess by using mv command

Answer (score 0):

Firs of all - take default **.htaccess.txt** file form your versions OpenCart pakage.

Now, you have to rename **.htaccess.txt** into **.htaccess**. It's not so easy on Windows. Open it with notepad and then Save As the file, renaming it to **.htaccess** without `.txt`.

Although, make sure that you are using **Apache** webserver, because only

If you are using address like this http://127.0.0.1/ - your rewrite base is `RewriteBase /`.

In SEO URL you should use only Latin symbols, digits, minus(-) and underscore (_). No spaces or other special characters.

**UPDATED**

There is SEO field in every category, product, manufacturer. You should fill SEO field of each of them to SEO URL (or better SEO PRO) works correct.

**UPDATED 2**

If apache doesn't see .htaccess file - you should go to apache .conf file and add after VirtualHost block

```
<Directory /var/www/html/your_folder/>
    Options Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

Directory - is a path from your virtual server root. Restart apache. Should work.

Comment: I'm reinstall all, i use ocStore-3.0.2.0, my OS Linux Mint, by mv command i rename .htaccess, but it dont help me. All links return me 404 error, except link from footer, but they still have ugly url like `http://127.0.0.1/index.php?route=account/return/add`

Comment: Know this version. Are you using SEO URL or SEO PRO. Suggests you SEO PRO. You can switch them in settings

Comment: And, as an experiment, lets try to make rewrite base like this RewriteBase /var/www/html/opencurt/ . Not sure, but have to try although.

Comment: switching on seo pro dont return 404, but links dont change and they stay common like `http://127.0.0.1/index.php?route=product/category&path=17`

Comment: Go to category ID17 in your admin and add a SEO URL

Comment: Adding `RewriteBase /var/www/html/opencurt/` don't help, `my category_id=17` have seo url software, but changing between seo pro and common seo url also dont help.

Comment: Change back to RewriteBase /. Tell me. If you open category id 17 on you store, is there anything in SEO URL field in it?

Comment: May be in's not obvious, there is SEO field in every category, product, manufacturer. If you want it to work - should fill SEO field of each of them to SEO URL (or better SEO PRO) works correct.